# make a Javascript array from php echo output

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

javascript help: i have a php page that echos

> ['A', 28.006660938911], ['B', 71.993339061089]

now i need this converted into an array in javascript, but in ajax, 
"var myData = new Array($http.responseText);" 
does not work

Comment: JSON is your friend: how can `json_encode` be used here? (Make sure to use the correct flags! :-) Also, this has been asked on SO like a bazillion times... on the JavaScript side use the appropriate JSON decoding, of course. There is no such `Array` constructor that takes a string. It just doesn't work like that.

Comment: I second what Pst said.  JSON will undoubtedly be the easiest (and probably most efficient) way to accomplish this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If given string is:

```
var s = "['A', 28.006660938911], ['B', 71.993339061089]";
```

1. try evaluating it (if you have no access to the PHP code you are
   using):

   ```
   var array = eval("[" + s + "]");
   ```
2. try changing the response to JSON format (if you HAVE access to
   that PHP code):

   ```
   echo json_encode(array(array('A', 28.006660938911), array('B', 71.993339061089)));
   ```
3. if i am wrong and you are given with two different arrays, try
   splitting the string first

Answer (score 0):

```
var myJSONObject = <?php echo json_encode($someArray); ?>
alert(  myJSONObject.keyInTheArray  )
```